# How to find all items that have no related objects?

Tags: graphql

There are two related tables A and B. The relation is one to many - A may point to the multiple entities in B.

Example:

*Table A*

```
id | title
--------
1  | 'title 1'
2  | 'title 2'
```

*Table B*

```
id | id_from_a
--------
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

I want to find all entities in table A that *do not* have anything in table B using graphQL.

For time being I am using the following contraption:

```
query getData {
  table_a(where: {_not: {table_b: {id_from_a: {_neq: -9999}}}}) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

It works, but it is ugly as hell, so I guess there should be some better graphql solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a while trying to solve this exact problem. For anyone that comes across this in the future, this is what I ended up with:

```
query myQuery {
  table_a(where: {_not: {table_b: {}}}) {
    id
    etc...
  }
}
```

It's not super intuitive, but just leaving `table_b` blank actually worked for me.